# How to get the handle used to drag a draggable when having multiple handles

Tags: draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, handle, jquery-draggable

I am using [Jquery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)
My draggable is having four handles on all four sides viz (top, bottom, left and right) using which draggable can be dragged in respective direction

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    handle: '.top, .bottom, .left, .right'
});
```

Well I can get the direction of drag and set the `axis` once the drag starts, but what if `bottom handle` is being used to drag to `left direction`.

So is there any way to know which handle is being used to drag a draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got an answer to my question, and I am posting it here so as to help others in future

```
$('. draggable').draggable({
    handle: '.top, .bottom, .left, .right'
    start : function(event, ui) 
    {
        console.log(event.originalEvent.target);
                 //OR
        console.log(event.originalEvent.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget);
    }
});
```